# Impossible to install Homebrew on a Macbook M1 Pro

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

My company provided me with a new Macbook pro (14", 2021, Monterey 12.6) and this is my first macbook.

I am trying to install Flutter + Dart, but for that I require **Homebrew**.

I tried following [the official guide](https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/3.html) to install Homebrew, but I am stuck at the is line:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

When attempting to execute the command, this is how my shell looks like:

[image]

- there is no password prompt
- nothing happens, it just stay that way indefinitely
- the terminal window bar changed for "curl + zsh"

Why is it not working? Could it be a security restriction from my company?

Comment: Have you installed the Xcode command line tools? If you aren't sure, try running `gcc --version`. If they're installed, then you'll get a version. If they aren't, macOS will prompt you to install them.

Comment: I have installed XCode from the App Store and already launched it. I remembered accepting some licences. I tried running your command line and this is what I get: `Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

Comment: Apparently this is because my company installed a firewall. They are investigating the issue for me.